# What type of furnace vent pipe is this?

Tags: furnace, roof, vent, exhaust-vent

I need to extend my furnace vent pipe up 2 foot above the ridge of my roof to comply with IBC. So I need to couple this pipe somehow and extend it up. Any idea what type of pipe this is and how I would extend it?

[image]

Comment: My first thought is asbestos

Comment: Definitely looks like asbestos.  It's a fiber, not metal or plastic, and the only fiber that I am aware of that could possibly be used for a furnace vent would be asbestos.  You might want to consider replacing the entire thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asbestos. ([lgam.info/asbestos-cement-pipe](http://www.lgam.info/asbestos-cement-pipe))

[image]

You'd need cast couplings: ([ebay, Smith Blair Industrial Ad](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Smith-Blair-Industrial-Ad-Cast-Iron-Coupling-Asbestos-Cement-Pipe-Piping-1960s-/150470731196))

[image]